# Cascading DropDownList in a web part?

Tags: dropdown, ajax, spservices

Is there a standard way to implement this?  Any solution would have to make use of AJAX.  I am considering two possible methods at the moment:

1. Try to find a way to use the ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit to do this (can this even be done in SharePoint?)
2. Use some sort of jQuery plugging for Cascading Dropdowns and find a way to connect it to my data.

Are both of these viable methods? If anyone has tried this before and has any recommendations I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the CascadingDropDown from the AJAX Control Toolkit. I would advise against using this in your SharePoint web part - and would advise using the client object model to do filtering within jQuery events (`ie $('select.class').change(function(){});`).

Chris O'Brien's articles mentioned in Matt Taylor's reply are great. You should be able to build cascading drop downs reasonably quickly using this method - and it will be far more performant than using Cascading Drop Down controls or an UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 2):

[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)?

Comment: Btw, SPServices does client-side filtering, and does not provide good performance :( so for huge lists or for "deep" cascading it is not the best solution. But anyway, it's the most simple way to implement cascading dropdowns in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your proposed solutions are viable, SharePoint is just an ASP.NET application after all.  I am not aware of a "standard" way to implement either however I have successfully used both.

1. To ensure I could make use of the ASP.NET AJAX toolkit from any page on my site I added the following directive to my Master Page and ensured my solution deployed the assembly to the GAC: <%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" %>

   You could also try looking at [this CodePlex solution by Daniel Larsen](http://sharepointajax.codeplex.com/) (I haven't tried it so not sure if it would be useful for your situation).
2. Anything you want to know about jQuery in SharePoint then look no further than [Jaap Vossers' blog](http://blog.vossers.com/index.php/category/jquery/)

Finally, I would strongly recommend reading [this series of articles that Chris O'Brien wrote on jQuery and AJAX in SharePoint](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/01/sp2010-ajax-part-8-transitioning.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the cascading drop-down-list web part as discussed in the article - http://datacogs.com/datablogs/archive/2007/08/26/641.aspx

Hope it will help you. :)